# Chinese symbols on teapot

Tags: translation, character-identification, seal

[image]

I bought this teapot and wondered what the symbols represent.

Comment: 福如東海 長流水 壽比南山 不老松.

Answer (score 3):

> 福如東海長流水，壽比南山不老松

Blessings of fortunes as boundless as the vast waters of the [East Sea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/East_China_Sea), and longevity of the immortal pines of the [Zhōngnán Mountains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zhongnan_Mountains)